# Upload Max File Size not changing when php.ini is changed

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

So, I've basically tried everything possible to change the upload max filesize limit on my wordpress website with no results.

I created a whole new Amazon Linux 2 AMI instance in AWS and followed their tutorial to download Wordpress and set everything up. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html).
I also moved my Domain from NameCheap to AWS using Route 53.

After that, I wanted to migrate a website from another domain to this one, but in order to do that, I have to upload a file larger than 2M.

So, I ssh'd into my instance and changed the following php.ini file settings to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

The php.ini file I changed is the one that is being loaded and is shown when running

```
php --ini
```

This changed my upload file size limit from 2M to 1M in the Add New Media section in Wordpress.
I then looked into the functions.php file in the theme twentytwenty folder (This theme comes with the WordPress installation).

There was no override to these settings to I added them myself, but again, no results, so I removed them again.

Lastly, I added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

But this just crashed the website.

After each of these changes I was restarting the httpd, mariadb and php-fpm services with sudo...

I am running out of options.. Does anyone have any other ideas?

EDIT: When I see the phpinfo.php file that I added on the website, the settings **are** updated. It's just not showing in wordpress.

Comment: the `php.ini` file loaded by the CLI seen when you do a `php --ini` from the terminal is Not Necessarily the one used by the web server.

Comment: The names you used in the `.htaccess` attempt are wrong. They are all `php_admin_value` rather than `php_value`

Comment: create a web page script that contains only `<?php phpinfo();?>` and then look at the value in `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the phpinfo webpage and the file net to Loaded configuration file is the same as the one in php --ini and it's the one I edited. I also tried the .htaccess edit by replacing php_value by php_admin_value and the website still crashed

Comment: Another thing that can happens is the on-the-fly configuration. If nothing that you follow from the other comments, you'll need to check if your code have `ini_set()` function modifying those cited properties in your question

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes I would think that Wordpress would not implement anything like this in their themes that come with their installations... I checked the functions.php file like I said but I really doubt a new fresh installation without any theme changes or plugins would be overriding php.ini settings... However, If you have other files in mind, please tell me which ones and I will check for that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to restart your `php-fpm` with:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

or

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS8 you will need to

1. Edit php.ini
2. Restart php-fpm  systemctl restart php-fpm
3. Restart httpd  systemctl restart httpd
4. for file uploading problems add MAX_FILE_SIZE to html pages

Comment: What do you mean with "edit php.ini" ? What should we edit ? Can you [edit] your answer to more explain ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multisite there is also an option for the max upload file size in the multisite network settings
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/increase-media-file-maximum-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31879376)